# What is the significance of Goldstein's book in 1984?

Tags: nineteen-eighty-four

In 1984 by George Orwell, Goldstein's book *The Theory and Practice of Oligarchical Collectivism* is given roughly 30 pages of text, is largely drawn out, and seems unimportant compared to the rest of the novel. What is its significance? Couldn't the book largely be summed up in a page or two of summary from the narrator?